# Timeshift doesn't work on elementary os 6

Tags: release-odin, backup

I am pretty a newbie in the linux word but I have been using elementary os for about one year. I recently installed Elementary os 6 (I am late, I know) but I've an issue with Timeshift that I am not able to solve.
I used Timeshift on my previous version of elementary in order to have a backup of the system (along with deja dups to backup the file), the problem is that on elementary 6 timeshift doesn't work: when I open the application it asks me for authentication but after I enter the password the application just doesn't open.

If I try to open it from the terminal i get the following message:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest looking at the bug report [here](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/391). Also, Odin (0.6) was just released, so you are not ***that*** late!

Comment: Also, [check this out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified)